# vb.net VB 2010 Underscore and small rectangles in string outputs?

Tags: vb.net, string, unicode, ascii

I've made some good progress with my first attempt at a program, but have hit another road block.  I'm taking standard output (as a string) froma console CMD window (results of dsquery piped to dsget) and have found small rectangles in the output.  I tried using Regex to clean the little bastards but it seems they are related to the _ (underscore), which I need to keep (to return 2000/NT logins). Odd thing is - when I copy the caharcter and paste it into VS2K10 Express it acts like a carrige return??

Any ideas on finding out what these little SOB's are -- and how to remove them?

Going to try using /U or /A CMD switch next..

Answer (score 0):

The square is often just used whenever a character is not displayable.  The character could very well be a CR.  You can use a Regular Expression to just get normal characters or remove the CR LF characters using [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Comment: I've tried -- they are only filtered out by using the underscore "_".

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using the string.replace function, and I am wondering if you are replacing the wrong character or something like that.  If all your trying to do is remove a carriage return I would skip the regular expressions and stick with the string.replace.

Something like this should work...

`strInputString = strInputString.replace(chr(13), "")`

If not could you post a line or two of code.

On a side note, this might give some other examples....

[Character replacement in strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319191/vb-net-character-replacement-in-strings)